Determine (in 2 iterations)
A company following the reorder level policy has the following costs associated with a given product: ordering cost of 100 monetary units (u.m.) per order; stock holding cost of 12 u.m. per unit per year; stockout cost of 180 u.m. per unit. The lead time is random with a normal distribution, with a mean of 0.2 years and a standard deviation of 0.05 years. Demand is deterministic, with a uniform value of 50 units per year.
Determine (in 2 iterations) the values of the order quantity and reorder point in order to minimize the total stock cost. For the final solution obtained, calculate the stockout probability per cycle, the stockout probability per year, the safety stock, the average number of units short per cycle, and the service level. Consider that what happens in one cycle is statistically independent of what happens in another cycle.

Please see our policy on homework questions: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/can-i-ask-a-homework-question-on-or-se.
